# ElasticSearch Create Index TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I'm using the elasticsearch npm module. Creating an Index results in a TypeError whose message is:

```
Unable to build a path with those params. Supply at least index
```

The code I'm using looks like:

```
    var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
        host: 'localhost:9200',
        log: 'trace'
    });

    client.indices.create('myindex', function (err, resp) {
        if (err)
            console.log('failed to create ElasticSearch index, ' + err.message);
        else
            console.log('successfully created ElasticSearch index');
    });
```

According to the [index create docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-indices-create), I should be able to pass a string with the name of the index. I am confused as to why it's failing in general, and why the error message refers to a path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument for `create()` needs to be a dict. Try:

```
client.indices.create({index: 'myindex'}, function (err, resp) {
    if (err)
        console.log('failed to create ElasticSearch index, ' + err.message);
    else
        console.log('successfully created ElasticSearch index');
});
```

Comment: Excellent. I had to change `{name: 'myindex'}` to `{index: 'myindex'}` to get it to work in the end.